# How to create a vertical stacked bar chart with Recharts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bar-chart, visualization, recharts

I am trying to simply swap the x an y axis on a bar chart using recharts.

However, when I try to switch the layout from horizontal bars to vertical, my chart gets wonky and is not my desired layout.

My desired chart consists of 4 bars stacked on top of each other. The y axis is the name of the bar and the x axis is the value of that bar.

Below is my code and a codesandbox link:

**codesandbox**: https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-bar-chart-forked-6ksutx?file=/src/App.tsx:176-180

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";
import {
  BarChart,
  Bar,
  XAxis,
  YAxis,
  CartesianGrid,
  Tooltip,
  Legend
} from "recharts";


const data = [
  {
    name: "A",
    value: 5
  },
  {
    name: "B",
    value: 10
  },
  {
    name: "C",
    value: 15
  },
  {
    name: "D",
    value: 20
  }
];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BarChart width={500} height={300} data={data} layout="vertical">
      <XAxis dataKey="name" type="category" />
      <YAxis dataKey="value" type="number" />
      <Bar dataKey="name" fill="#8884d8" />
      <Tooltip/>
    </BarChart>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the XAxis type to number did the trick for me, below example is how to implement it on a BarChart ( Stack )

```
import {
  BarChart,
  CartesianGrid,
  XAxis,
  YAxis,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  Bar,
} from "recharts";

const BarChartComponent = () => {
  const data = [
    {
      name: "Page A",
      uv: 4000,
      pv: 2400,
      amt: 2400,
    },
    {
      name: "Page B",
      uv: 3000,
      pv: 1398,
      amt: 2210,
    },
    {
      name: "Page C",
      uv: 2000,
      pv: 9800,
      amt: 2290,
    },
    {
      name: "Page D",
      uv: 2780,
      pv: 3908,
      amt: 2000,
    },
    {
      name: "Page E",
      uv: 1890,
      pv: 4800,
      amt: 2181,
    },
    {
      name: "Page F",
      uv: 2390,
      pv: 3800,
      amt: 2500,
    },
    {
      name: "Page G",
      uv: 3490,
      pv: 4300,
      amt: 2100,
    },
  ];
  return (
    <BarChart
      layout="vertical"
      width={500}
      height={500}
      data={data}
      margin={{
        top: 30,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 10,
        left: 10,
      }}
    >
      <CartesianGrid stroke="#f5f5f5" />
      <XAxis type="number" />
      <YAxis dataKey="name" type="category" />
      <Tooltip />
      <Legend />
      <Bar dataKey="pv" stackId="a" fill="#8884d8" />
      <Bar dataKey="uv" stackId="a" fill="#82ca9d" />
    </BarChart>
  );
};

export default BarChartComponent;
```